# Laravel SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I am new to laravel and im stuck with my relationshops what looks like the following

Categories

```
    id  name            slug
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    3   Location        location
    4   Outfits         outfits
    5   Other           other
```

sub_categories

```
  id    category_id     name                slug
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     12     3           Club                club
     13     3           Home / Hotel        home-hotel
     14     3           Outdoor             outdoor
     15     3           Studio              studio
     16     4           Bikini / Swimwear   bikini-swimwear
     17     4           Dress               dress
     19     4           Jeans               jeans
     35     5           Dancing             dancing
```

Category model

```
<?php

class Category extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function subcategory()
    {
        return  $this->belongsToMany('subcategory', "sub_categories");
    }
}
```

And i get the following error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'sub_categories' (SQL: select `sub_categories`.*, `sub_categories`.`category_id` as `pivot_category_id`, `sub_categories`.`subcategory_id` as `pivot_subcategory_id` from `sub_categories` inner join `sub_categories` on `sub_categories`.`id` = `sub_categories`.`subcategory_id` where `sub_categories`.`category_id` = ?) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 1, ))
```

Could please someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does the query that crashes look like?

Comment: it is an eloquent relationship

Comment: {{ $category->subcategory->name }} this is the point

Comment: I think you'll need to describe your intended model for categories and subcategories. As it's mapped (as far as I can see), a category can have many subcategories, and a subcategory can belong to multiple categories at once. Is that what you're intending?

Comment: yes thats what im trying to dp

Comment: The problem would seem to be that two tables are mapped to the same name `sub_category` at once. A many-to-many relationship requires 3 tables (category/subcategory/category_subcategory) which need distinct names. If two of the tables get the same name, you'll get the error you're showing.

Comment: thak you @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Wrote up a short summary for future searchers, if you want to write a more detailed one on what you actually did to fix it, I'll remove mine.

Answer (score 1):

you should give different aliases names to same table

change this

```
 inner join `sub_categories`
```

to

```
   inner join `sub_categories` as sc   
                                   ^^--//-this alias use it instead of sub_categories
```

in your query it will be

```
    select `sub_categories`.*, sc.`category_id` as `pivot_category_id`, sc.`subcategory_id` as `pivot_subcategory_id` from `sub_categories` inner join `sub_categories` sc on sc.`id` = `sub_categories`.`subcategory_id` where `sub_categories`.`category_id` = ?) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 1, )
```

Example:

```
 select * from table1 as t1
 inner join table1 as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
```

**Clarification of your error:** `Not unique table/alias`

you are joining same table  without aliases to different between them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like that two tables are mapped to the same name sub_category at once.

A many-to-many relationship requires 3 tables (category/subcategory/category_subcategory) which need distinct names. If two of the tables get mapped with the same name, you'll get the error you're showing.

Change one of the mappings, and you should be up and running.

Comment: How might you go about doing this "change one of the mappings" regarding Eloquent and $model->belongsToMany('OtherModel') ? I've run into a similar situation, but I am using the 3 table relationship that you've described above. I am receiving an almost identical error.  Hmmm...